# How to delete local and remote branch using git

Tags: git, git-branch

So right now these are the branches I have:

```
WalnutiQ> git branch -a
* develop
  feature-model_in_javascript
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature-model_in_javascript
  remotes/origin/master
```

My goal is to delete the branch feature-model_in_javascript so I tried:

```
WalnutiQ> git branch -d feature-model_in_javascript
Deleted branch feature-model_in_javascript (was 4604f04).
```

So now when I check my branchs I get:

```
WalnutiQ> git branch -a 
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature-model_in_javascript # <== HOW DO I DELETE THIS????
  remotes/origin/master
```

How do I delete that remote branch? I manually deleted it by clicking the delete button on https://github.com/WalnutiQ/WalnutiQ/branches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have already manually deleted the branch on the upstream server, then use

```
git fetch -p
```

to "prune" your remote tracking branches. Any branches under `remotes/origin` that no longer exist on the server will be deleted from your local repository.

Comment: @GregHewgill I think `git branch -p` is used for  remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote. I'm not familiar with remote-tracking branch, but it seems remote-tracking is local branch that tracked with remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below to delete the remote branch:

```
git push origin :<branch>
```

remove remote tags is the same.

You can find details here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: WalnutiQ> git push origin :feature-model_in_javascript
error: unable to delete 'feature-model_in_javascript': remote ref does not exist

Comment: @QuinnLiu Try `git branch -r` to list the remote branches. Check the link you provided, seems no branch named feature-model_in_javascript

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more modern syntax for deleting remote branches (*perhaps* easier to remember) is:

> git push origin --delete <branchName>